# Issue in Integrating wso2 EI 6.0 with IBM MQ 9.0.1

Tags: authentication, integration, ibm-mq, apache-axis, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to integrate wso2 ei 6.0.0 with IBM MQ 9.0.1. I have followed the below document:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Configure+with+IBM+WebSphere+MQ

I have generated jar wmq-client-9.0.0.1.jar and placed JTA jar as well in lib of EI.

Please find my JMS transport receiver and sender configuration from axis2.xml below:

```
   <transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
<parameter name="default" locked="false">
<parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/C:/Users/*****/****/jndiDirectory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">MyQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">admin</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">admin</parameter>
</parameter>

<parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory1" locked="false">
<parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/C:/Users/*****/***/jndiDirectory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">MyQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">admin</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">admin</parameter>
</parameter>
</transportReceiver>

<transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender">
<parameter name="default" locked="false">
<!-- <parameter name="vender.class.loader.enabled">false</parameter> -->
<parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/C:/Users/*****/***/jndiDirectory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">MyQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">admin</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">admin</parameter>
</parameter>

<parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory1" locked="false">
<parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/C:/Users/*****/***/jndiDirectory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">MyQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">admin</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">admin</parameter>
</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

when I create a proxy service with JMS as transport I get the below error
2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED Connecting to WebSphere MQ.

I am not sure about username and password to be given in axis2.xml.

NOTE: I have opened MQ Explored as admin and created Queue Manager, LocalQueue and Initial context in MQ.

Any input on this will be helpful

Comment: Check the AMQERR01.LOG file found in the queue manager's errors directory, this will show you the cause of the 2035.

Comment: The error file is not there in MQ folder, I got the below mentioned error in wso2 EI server
errorcom.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
So the connection itself is not established between EI and MQ.

Comment: In the directory where you installed MQ you will find a path like qmgrs/<queue manager name>/errors.

Comment: Inside MQ folder, i have two subfolders .metadata and WMQ Explorer Tests Data. In either of this log file is not there. i suspect, there is no errors generated from MQ explorer, hence err file is not created.
Is that right?

Comment: That would be the directory where you installed MQ Explorer.  I am asking for the errors from the queue manager you created.